# gofabric8 Install on Windows 10 Pro with minishift fails

Tags: openshift, fabric8

gofabric8 install on Windows 10 Pro fails with:

```
Unable to get status fork/exec C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8
\bin\minishift.exe: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
```

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Virtualization: Use Hyper-V exclusively...happily running Docker for Windows for a while (not Docker machine, no virtualbox)

It was difficult to decide between various gofabric8 install instructions, but it appeared that I didn't have to install Minishift first, but I could just start gofabric8 with --minishift switch and that it would grab and configure everything.
[Install Fabric8](https://fabric8.io/guide/getStarted/gofabric8.html)

- I downloaded gofabric8-windows-amd64.exe and put it in a folder named
  C:\fabric8
- Renamed the exe in that folder to simply fabric8.exe
- Put that folder in my PATH.

Here is the version:

```
    C:\fabric8>gofabric8 version
    gofabric8, version 0.4.120 (branch: 'master', revision: 'a1f42fe')
      build date:       '20170222-10:59:23'
      go version:       '1.7.1'
```

Then following that guide:

```
    C:\fabric8>gofabric8 start --minishift

    Downloading https://github.com/jimmidyson/minishift/releases/download/v1.0.0-beta.4/minishift-windows-amd64.exe...
    Downloaded C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8\bin\minishift.exe
    Downloading https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.4.9/bin/windows/amd64/kubectl.exe...
    Downloaded C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8\bin\kubectl.exe
    Downloading https://github.com/openshift/origin/releases/download/v1.3.1/openshift-origin-client-tools-v1.3.1-dad658de7465ba8a234a4fb40b5b446a45a4cee1-windows.zip...
    Downloaded oc
    Downloading https://github.com/fabric8io/funktion-operator/releases/download/v1.0.9/funktion-operator-windows-amd64.exe...
    Downloaded C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8\bin\funktion 
    using the executable C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8\bin\minishift.exe Unable to get status fork/exec C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8\bin\minishift.exe: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.


    C:\fabric8>
```

That folder looks fine as it was just created by gofabric8

```
     Directory of C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy\.fabric8\bin

    02/25/2017  09:20 AM    <DIR>          .
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM    <DIR>          ..
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM           129,195 funktion
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM        80,019,456 kubectl.exe
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM            10,759 LICENSE
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM           129,195 minishift.exe
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM        95,878,144 oc.exe
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM        19,317,606 oc.zip
    02/25/2017  09:20 AM            20,497 README.md
```

I found some posts about $HOME variables, so I created an environment variable named HOME with value of C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy.fabric8\bin  but that made no difference.

I even added C:\Users\FriendOfEntropy.fabric8\bin to my PATH and that didn't help either